# Running single cucumber feature doesn't load step definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a cucumber feature at features/object/create_object.feature. It passes when I execute all of my features with the 'cucumber' command. I'm trying to execute this feature by itself using these commands:

```
cucumber features/object/create_object.feature
rake features FEATURE=features/object/create_object.feature
```

However, all step definitions for this feature come up as undefined:

```
Using the default profile...
-------UUUUUUUUUUUU
```

I've also tried disabling the profile with "--no-profile", but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you need to tell cucumber how to locate the step definitions when running features in subdirectories of `./features`:

`rake features FEATURE=features/object/create_object.feature REQUIRE=features`

Using `cucumber` from the command line per your example didn't work for me -- I had to add `--require`:

`cucumber --require features features/object/create_object.feature`

More in [this blog post](http://lmarburger.github.com/2009/09/cucumber-features-in-subdirectories.html).

Comment: --require set me straight. Thanks!

Comment: Why does it not check for the existence of the "features" directory and do this automatically, like rspec does for the "spec" directory?

Answer (score 6):

Better approach is to update your add **-r features** to cucumber.yml file.

See [Cucumber steps not automatically loaded when running features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620983/cucumber-steps-not-automatically-loaded-when-running-features)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but the require feature did not solve it
Instead I got around the problem by using tags

So instead of calling

> cucumber  features/accounts.feature

I call

> cucumber --tags @account features

where "@account" goes before the scenario

> @current   Scenario: Anonymous user
>   can create an account
>       Given an anonymous user

works fine. All steps.rb files are loaded